# XSD - attribute only few are mandatory

Tags: xsd, attributes

Below is the xml sample.

```
<Custom>
    <Entry Key="ClientApp.DataContext.JobId" Type="String" Value="105161"></Entry>
    <Entry Key="ClientApp.DataContext.JobNumber" Type="String" Value="PCSQ test"></Entry>
    <Entry Key="Abstract" Type="String" Value="Emsur"></Entry>
    <Entry Key="TempID" Type="String" Value="12345"></Entry>
    <Entry Key="Lot" Type="String" Value="6789"></Entry>
</Custom>
```

Below is the XSD auto generated by Visual Studio 2019.

```
      <xs:element name="Custom">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Entry">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="Key" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

**Context:** The XSD generated says all the attributes (Key,Value,Type) are required. We need Key="Abstract" and its Value="Emsur" & Key="TempID" and its Value="12345" mandatorily. Other attributes like ClintApp.JobId and ClientApp.JobNumber are optional.

**Question:** How to validate if Abstract has value and Lot has Value in it keeping other attributes as optional?

Thanks.

Comment: The attributes you have are named `Key`, `Type` and `Value`. `Abstract` or `TempID` seem to be possible values of the `Key` attribute. It is not clear what you would want to make mandatory, perhaps an enumeration helps. As for assert(ions), keep in mind that that requires XSD 1.1 support (the built-in XML stacks in Java or .NET, for instance, have only XSD 1.0 support).

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question - it's not at all clear what you want.

Comment: sorry @MartinHonnen & mamift for not posting the question clearly. i have edited and posted it again. let me know if you guys understand what is my ask now. Thanks.

Comment: Part of the requirements to have certain attribute value combinations might be expressable as assertions. But can you use an XML parser/validator with XSD 1.1. support?

Comment: can use xsd 1.1 for validation. checking your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 assert:

```
<xs:element name="Custom">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Entry">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="Key" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:assert test="some $entry in Entry satisfies $entry/@Key = 'Abstract' and $entry/@Value = 'Emsur'"/>
          <xs:assert test="some $entry in Entry satisfies $entry/@Key = 'TempID' and $entry/@Value = '12345'"/>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```